# Guardar archivo .KML con asksaveasfile en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo una función **generar** la cual crea un archivo KML.
Este archivo lo quiero guardar con el metodo **asksaveasfile** pero no logro realizarlo, alguien me puede decir en que estoy fallando en mi funcion.

```
def generar():
    global resultado    
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    kml.newpoint(name="Punto Generado", coords=[(longitud,latitud)])
    resultado = kml.save("\\utm.kml")
    resultado = asksaveasfile(mode = 'w', filetypes =[('KML', '*.KML')])
    if latitud and longitud != "":
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Archivo KML Generado correctamente")
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("\\utm.kml")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "El archivo no se genero.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`asksaveasfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile) utliza [open](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#open) para abrir el archivo. Lo que necesitas sería usar [`asksaveasfilename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename), que devuelve el path elegido para guardar el archivo o una cadena vacía (si el usuario canceló el proceso de guardar).

El código que hace lo que buscas sería:

```
def generar():
    global resultado    
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    kml.newpoint(name="Punto Generado", coords=[(longitud,latitud)])
    resultado = asksaveasfilename(filetypes =[('KML', '*.KML')])
    
    if(resultado)
        if latitud and longitud != "":
            kml.save(resultado)

            messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Archivo KML Generado correctamente")
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(resultado)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "El archivo no se genero.")
```

Comment: si pudieras explicarme la linea 6 porfavor

Comment: La linea 6 está en blanco. Si cuento desde el comienzo del código de la función llego a if(resultado). Como es la linea que necesitas que explique???

Comment: Perdón esa misma if(resultado)

Comment: No pasa nada c: `if(resultado)` es equivalente a `if(bool(resultado))`. Es decir, el contenido de la variable se convierte en booleano y si el resultado es verdadero, el if da verdadero, si es falso, el if da falso. En Python, las cadenas vacías son consideradas falsas. Eso se puede complejizar más, por ejemplo `if(resultado and color or red == '')` por dar un ejemplo. Todo eso equivale a `if(bool(resultado) and bool(color) or red == '')`

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias

Comment: De nada Daxtrox c: